# How to reduce image size and resize image together for my coding?

Tags: php

How can I resize an image and reduce its file size?

Here's my code for reducing an image's file size, which works correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    include("connect.php");
    // created compressed JPEG file from source file
    function compressImage($source_image, $compress_image) {
        $image_info = getimagesize($source_image);  
        if ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') { 
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            imagejpeg($source_image, $compress_image, 75);
        } elseif ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
            imagegif($source_image, $compress_image, 75);
        } elseif ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            imagepng($source_image, $compress_image, 6);
        }       
        return $compress_image;
    }

    $upload_dir = "test/";          
    $new_image_name_rand_num = RAND(0,100);
    $new_image_name_rand_text = substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'),0,7);

    $image_name_new = $pet_ref_id."-".$new_image_name_rand_num."-".$new_image_name_rand_text;
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['pet_image']['name']);
    $newfilename = $image_name_new. '.' . end($temp);
    $upload_file = $upload_dir.$newfilename;


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pet_image']['tmp_name'],$upload_file))
    {
        $source_image = $upload_file;
        $image_destination = $upload_dir."".$newfilename;
        $compress_images = compressImage($source_image, $image_destination);
    }
}
?>

<form class="form" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input name="pet_image" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I reduce the file size and resize the image together like this, it neither reduces the file size nor resizes the image. What is the correct way to do both at the same time?

Here's the combined code that doesn't work correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    include("connect.php");
    // created compressed JPEG file from source file
    function compressImage($source_image, $compress_image) {
        $image_info = getimagesize($source_image);  
        if ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') { 
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            imagejpeg($source_image, $compress_image, 75);
        } elseif ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
            imagegif($source_image, $compress_image, 75);
        } elseif ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            imagepng($source_image, $compress_image, 6);
        }       
        return $compress_image;
    }


    function shazam($file, $w, $h) {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

        if ($width > $height) {
            $r = ($w / $width);
            $newwidth = $w;
            $newheight = ceil($height * $r);
        } 

        if ($width < $height) {
            $r = ($h / $height);
            $newheight = $h;
            $newwidth = ceil($width * $r);
        } 

        if ($width == $height) {
            $newheight = $h;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        $tgt = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        imagecopyresampled($tgt, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        return $tgt;
    }

    $upload_dir = "test/";          
    $new_image_name_rand_num = RAND(0,100);
    $new_image_name_rand_text = substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'),0,7);

    $image_name_new = $pet_ref_id."-".$new_image_name_rand_num."-".$new_image_name_rand_text;
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['pet_image']['name']);
    $newfilename = $image_name_new. '.' . end($temp);
    $upload_file = $upload_dir.$newfilename;


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pet_image']['tmp_name'],$upload_file))
    {     
        $source_image = shazam($upload_file, 850, 850);
        $image_destination = $upload_dir."".$newfilename;
        $compress_images = compressImage($source_image, $image_destination);
    }
}
?>



<form class="form" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input name="pet_image" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```